VBA program returns a Runtime Error '1004'
I am still new to VBA and I am getting a "runtime error '1004' "Method 'Add' of object 'Workbooks' failed". What might the issue be? I cannot seem to get VBA to automatically open the files and plot them in a specific template.
Here is my code:
Sub CopyDataFromCSVs()
    
    Dim srcPath As String
    Dim destPath As String
    Dim srcFile As String
    Dim destFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col As Range
    
    srcPath = "P:\Fluid Products Engineering\EOP Tester Data\Combination Program\Raw Data\"
    destPath = "P:\Fluid Products Engineering\EOP Tester Data\Combination Program\Data\"
    
    i = 1
    
    srcFile = Dir(srcPath & "*.csv")
    
    While srcFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(srcPath & srcFile)
        
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        
        With ws
            .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
            
            .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            
            For Each col In .Columns
                col.AutoFit
            Next col
        End With
        
        ws.Copy
        
        destFile = "Test" & CStr(i) & ".xlsx"
        
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destPath & destFile
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        Kill srcPath & srcFile
        
        srcFile = Dir
        
        i = i + 1
   
    Wend
    
    Do
    
    Dim templatePath As String
    Dim templateWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim templateDirectory As String

    templatePath = "P:\Fluid Products Engineering\EOP Tester Data\Combination Program\Template\PD Lab Data.xltx"

    If Dir(templatePath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Template file not found. Please provide a valid template path."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set templateWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(templatePath)

    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(Template:=templateWorkbook)

    newWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Fluid Products Engineering\EOP Tester Data\Combination Program\Data\"

    templateWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Loop
    
End Sub

I tried changing the workbook.add line to just open and it didn't really change anything.

You have to pass the full path/name of templateWorkbook - not the workbook object. `Workbooks.Add(template:=templateWorkbook.FullName)'

Please describe in detail what "plot them in a specific template" means. Your code doesn't do that. Usually you .Add a new instance of the template (e.g. Set templateWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(templatePath)), add (copy) some values to its sheet(s), and save it with a different name and file extension (templateWorkbook.SaveAs "...\FileName.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook).

@VBasic2008 I am using this program to convert csv's to xlxs. I then want the code to take the information that is in the xlxs files and import it into a template. The template will then put the information into graphs. I just need it to go through the folder and automatically import the data into the template and save it.
